# LibGit2Sharp how to push with kerberos authentication?

Tags: kerberos, git-push, libgit2sharp

I need to push branches from a Intranet application (Windows environment). Some users from one team can do this action. The Git local repository is hosted on the web server and the remote on another server. URL protocol is **https** and we use **Kerberos** authentication. I don't want the application's users enter their Windows userid and password.

So, as an initialization step, I configure the local repository according to the user:

```
        var m_Repo = new Repository(repoFldPathName);
        Configuration config = m_Repo.Config;
        config.Set<string>("user.name", m_UserName);
        config.Set<string>("http.sslVerify", "false");
        string url = string.Format(https://{0}@my-host.fr/folder/repo_name.git, m_UserName);
        Remote remote = m_Repo.Network.Remotes["origin"];
        if (remote != null)
        {
            if (remote.Url != url)
            {
                m_Repo.Network.Remotes.Remove("origin");
                m_Repo.Network.Remotes.Add("origin", url);
            }
        }
        else
            m_Repo.Network.Remotes.Add("origin", url);
```

And when it's time to push the branch "master" I prepare the push (as I seen on another post):

```
        PushOptions options = new PushOptions();
        Remote remote = m_Repo.Network.Remotes["origin"];
        Branch branch = m_Repo.Branches["master"];
        if (branch.Remote == null)
            m_Repo.Branches.Update(branch,
                b => b.Remote = remote.Name,
                b => b.UpstreamBranch = branch.CanonicalName);
        options.CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) => new DefaultCredentials();
        m_Repo.Network.Push(branch, options);
```

And after few minutes of execution, I get this exception :

```
  LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Failed to receive response: La requête doit être renvoyée

  Source=LibGit2Sharp
  StackTrace:
       à LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)
       à LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.ZeroResult(Int32 result)
       à LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_remote_push(RemoteSafeHandle remote, IEnumerable`1 refSpecs, GitPushOptions opts, Signature signature, String reflogMessage)
       à LibGit2Sharp.Network.Push(Remote remote, IEnumerable`1 pushRefSpecs, PushOptions pushOptions, Signature signature, String logMessage)
       à LibGit2Sharp.Network.Push(Remote remote, String pushRefSpec, PushOptions pushOptions, Signature signature, String logMessage)
       à LibGit2Sharp.NetworkExtensions.Push(Network network, IEnumerable`1 branches, PushOptions pushOptions)
       à LibGit2Sharp.NetworkExtensions.Push(Network network, Branch branch, PushOptions pushOptions)
       à CDM.ESD1_WSGINSTALL.Business.GitRepo.Push(brEnum brName) dans c:\PRIV\Projects\ESD1\ESD1_WSGINSTALL\ESD1_WSGINSTALL.Business\GitRepo.cs:ligne 72
       à CDM.ESD1WSGINSTALL.Commands.CharteView.DoBuildRPM(String id) dans c:\PRIV\Projects\ESD1\ESD1_WSGINSTALL\ESD1_WSGINSTALL\App_Code\Commands\CharteViewActivity\CharteView.cs:ligne 262
  InnerException:
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure that your server really speaks HTTPS?  This error would be consistent with not having an HTTPS endpoint.  (I ask this because in your comments below you talk about an OpenSSH password dialog, and that should never happen with an HTTPS endpoint.)

Answer (score 2):

I think the `DefaultCredentials` type is what you're after.

As stated by the **[xml documentation](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/a026f5d84e35f1df94bc3f30503429ef8a216209/LibGit2Sharp/DefaultCredentials.cs#L6-L9)**, it's *"A credential object that will provide the "default" credentials (logged-in user information) via NTLM or SPNEGO authentication."*

Settings the `PushOptions.CredentialsProvider` to the following should do the trick

```
CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) => new DefaultCredentials()
```

### Update

> When I use Git Extensions on my Windows machine to push a branch, (git push origin master --tag) a "OpenSSH" popup claims my password

Sadly, LibGit2Sharp doesn't support SSH yet. I'd suggest you to subscribe to the open issue **[#852](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/852)** to get notified about its progress.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the sentence. I'm not very familiar with delegates and lambda expressions. Can you detail your answer please ?

Comment: I added "options.CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) => new DefaultCredentials();". No exception, but no action when "m_Repo.Network.Push(branch, options);" is executed...

Comment: @P.Debrabant Duh. I made a mistake. The description was coherent, but the code suffered from a severe copy/paste error. Sorry for this. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @P.Debrabant Could you please elaborate on the *"but no action when "m_Repo.Network.Push(branch, options);" is executed..."* part?

Comment: Correction : after few minutes I get a LibGit2SharpException : Failed to receive response

Comment: @P.Debrabant What kind of Git server are you running against? How is it configured?

Comment: I don't have a lot of information about it. All that I know it's the https protocol of the url and the kerberos authentication. When I use Git Extensions on my Windows machine to push a branch, (git push origin master --tag) a "OpenSSH" popup claims my password.

Comment: The answer have been updated to account for your latest comment.